# Context-free grammar how to have unequal number of a's on either side of b

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I have been trying to create a CFG for the set
$\{w=a^iba^j \mid i \neq j\}$.

To my understanding, there are essentially 2 scenarios, one where there are more $a$s on the left side of $b$, and one where there are more $a$s on the right side of $b$.
So far I have come up with:
\begin{align}
S &= TbR \mid RbT \\
T &= aT \mid \varepsilon \\
R &= TaT
\end{align}
My intention is the have $R$ to always have more $a$s than $T$, however I don't think this is correct as $T$ can be greater than $R$ in this definition, as $R$ could take be just $a$ while $T$ is $aa$.

I need a bit of help defining 2 variables $T$ and $R$, where $R$ always has more $a$s than $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equal numbers of a’s on either side, then the middle is replaced by a+b or by ba+.

Comment: Thanks for your help! If anyone anyone was wondering for the final solution, I ended up with: `S=Tb|bT|aSa, T=aT|a`